# Is there a way to use Jackson's ObjectMapper to serialize streams?

Tags: java, json, stream, jackson, objectmapper

Is there a way to use Jackson's ObjectMapper to serialize `java.util.stream.Stream<T>`?

I'm not referring to Jackson's streaming API which lets you process JSON documents in chunks.
I'm also not referring to using Java's I/O streams like `java.io.InputStream` to read JSON files.

I'm referring to Java's streaming API introduced with JDK8.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public final class JsonSerializer {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JsonSerializer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public String serializeAsString(SimpleObjectBean bean) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return objectMapper.writerFor(SimpleObjectBean.class).writeValueAsString(bean);
    }

    public String serializeListAsString(List<SimpleObjectBean> beans) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return objectMapper.writerFor(List.class).writeValueAsString(beans);
    }

    // does not work
    public String serializeStreamAsString(Stream<SimpleObjectBean> beanStream) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return objectMapper.writerFor(Stream.class).writeValueAsString(beanStream);
    }

    // used as workaround. "converting" stream into iterator beforehand
    public String serializeIteratorAsString(Iterator<SimpleObjectBean> beanIterator) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return objectMapper.writerFor(Iterator.class).writeValueAsString(beanIterator);
    }

}
```

I'm using Jackson 2.9.5

Answer (score 1):

It is not good idea to serialize Streams, because Streams are meant not to be persistent. Moreover they can be traversed only once. Collections would be better choice in this case.
But it is possible to do something like:

```
new ObjectMapper().writerWithType(Iterator.class).writeValueAsString(stream.iterator());
```

Comment: I'm not sure why Streams not being meant for persistence is a problem. In a typical request/response scenario streams are as transient as collections in my opinion. Well, I can however see that being able to iterate a stream only once could be an issue, if the ObjectMapper would need to do that.
In best case the ObjectMapper would just do `return stream.map(bean -> toJson(bean))` returning the transformed input stream without terminating it...